# How to access UserID of Alexa Skill by using Flask Ask Library?

Tags: python, flask, alexa-skills-kit

I am using Flask Ask to develop my Alexa Skill. I want to give different permissions to different Users. For this I have to access the UserID. I have been searching for days now. I have read documentation of Flask Ask and there was not sufficient information about accessing UserID.

Comment: [It's in their full documentation](https://alexatutorial.com/flask-ask/requests.html). `UserId` is found inside a `session` object.

Comment: I have gone through this documentation. It does not return any thing when I use
'uid = session.user.userId'

infact it returns an error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'

Comment: and when i try to return `question(session.user.userId)` it gives internal error 500 on my Alexa test tab

Answer (score 1):

According to the amazon dev [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#session-object) for the Request Format : "Standard request types (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest, and SessionEndedRequest) include the session object.

Requests from interfaces such as AudioPlayer and PlaybackController are not sent in the context of a session, so they do not include the session object. The context.System.user and context.System.application objects provide the same user and application information as the same objects within session – see Context Object."

So I guess you are not using a standard request. Thus, you need to access the userId from the context object. The [documentation](https://flask-ask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requests.html#session-context-request-and-version-context-locals) for flask-ask has been updated to explain how to access that.

In short, you should do this:

```
from flask_ask import context    
uid = context.System.user.userId
```